# edx "Live Preview" and "View Live Version" button doesn't redirect to required page

Tags: javascript, python, open-source, edx

After making changes in a course on the Teacher side, there are options to preview changes and view live version but currently both options are not working properly and we have to append base url (www.abc.com/) in URL every time to preview changes or view live version.

We are using edx open code for providing open(free) courses for users from all over the world.
But we are stuck here, please assist us so we can move forward.

Thanks in Advance, 
Anjum

Comment: I think it would be helpful to post your problem at the [Open edX discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/edx-code)

Answer (score 4):

If you are in development, (ie using `settings=devstack`) check

**cms/envs/devstack.py**

```
LMS_BASE = "your lms url"`  // (normally `LMS_BASE = "localhost:8000"
```

If you are in production, check

**/edx/app/edxapp/cms.env.json**

```
LMS_BASE = "your lms url"
```